# Flutter - Firebase Realtime Database Problem

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have recently approached the world of flutter and now I have a problem, in practice I need to write during the first recording of data in a Realtime Database.

I created the void function (I've done the association   `final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();` before.

This is the function

```
void writeDB() async{
    User user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('user').equalTo(user.uid);
    databaseReference.child('user').set({
      'email': FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.email,
      'name': "",
      'nick': "",
      "score": "0"
    });
  }
```

And this is the signIn function :

```
  Future<String> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    UserCredential result = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
      writeDB();
    User user = result.user;
    return user.uid;
  }
```

The registration and login system with firebase works fine, but the database is not written

Any help?

Comment: which firebase rules are u using?

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: no, it just doesn't write anything, I also tried adding an await

Comment: do `print(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.email)

Comment: Done, but no output in the debug

Comment: then its not reaching the code there

Comment: mh, and what i have to do to solve? because the signin function work

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the new version of firebase auth. The `currentUser` property doesnt return a `Future`, try the following:

```
void writeDB() async{
    User user =  _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
    await databaseReference.child('user').set({
      'email': FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.email,
      'name': "",
      'nick': "",
      "score": "0"
    });
  }
```

Comment: I tried as you told me. it doesn't work anyway

Comment: Add a breakpoint inside the method writeDB()

Comment: Done, nothing changed

Comment: try `void writeDB() async{
    await databaseReference.child('user').set({
      "score": "0"
    });
  }`

Comment: In the signin method do print(result.user)

Comment: Done and the account info appears in the debug